# Teams bot trying to read receipts

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I'm triying to implement in a chat bot a feature to know the read receipt confirmation on Teams.
They add this functional [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.teams.teamsactivityhandler.onteamsreadreceiptasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) but I'm not receiving the event on the adapter and I don't not why...

I tried adding the permission ChatMessageReadReceipt.Read.Chat when the bot it's installed on teams but it's not working.

Comment: Could you please confirm that you have correctly subscribed to the teamsMembersReadMessage event in the bot's adapter. Ensure that you have implemented the event handler logic to handle the read receipt confirmation.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem... I'm not receiving the event, I have the builtin adapter and a middleware where I handle the events, but it's no reaching there. Other events like reactions or even bot installation are working but I do not receive anything when the message it's read.

Comment: Could you please share the request id and timestamp when you are not getting the event so that we can investigate further?

Comment: Could you please share the request details so that we can investigate further?